# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused only in artisan using laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm running a vagrant box and with laravel 5. For some reason when running `php artisan` it throws the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

This happens when I have my `host` set to `127.0.0.1`. When using `localhost` I get `File or directory not found`.

The strange part is that the website itself works fine in the browser. This **only** happens in `php artisan`.

I also tried changing ports between `3306` and `33060`.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I did the following in the laravel `index.php` file:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mydb','root','mypassword');
var_dump(get_class_methods($pdo));
die();
```

and it worked fine. Inside the `Connector.php` file I checked the variables being passed to the `PDO` constructor and they were identical to what I filled in above. What is going on?

Comment: Did you try do clean the cache?

Comment: @IagoMelanias i ran `composer dump` with no effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't believe I am posting this but I was in the wrong terminal tab. Instead of running `php artisan` on the VM i was running it directly in OSX... Obviously it won't connect to a database that does not exists.

Comment: Well.. you can downvote me, but it's a legitimate mistake anyone can make. No point in downvoting

Comment: Thanks for posting this "answer", the same just happened to me!